How to stop git from auto staging a restore on force push
When I force push my changes from my local repo to the remote repo, the changes get pushed, but the remote repo also automatically stages a RESTORE of my pushed changes.
Also, if there are any unstaged changes, they don't get restored.
Is there any way to push so that the repo essential does a hard reset to the pushed commit?
* When I try searching for a solution to this problem, I only see results for VS. I am not using VS, so I'm creating this post because I haven't found anything for my specific situation.

It sounds like you have a non-bare remote, containing a working folder. This is not recommended.

I am well aware this scenario sits outside the realm of recommended practice. This is a very small project with only one developer and I am looking to explore an unusual use case.

Potentially you could use a post-receive hook in the target repository to achieve your goal.
